# Mesh network for CommCare functionality for CommCare?

Tags: commcare

Is there a functionality in CommCare that would allow devices to exchanged data (specifically cases) in a "mesh" network mode or by bluetooth instead of purely by a data or wifi connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is not currently available in CommCare